# How can I make header not clickable for DataGridViewButtonColumn in a datagridview c#.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a + and - button (DataGridViewButtonColumn) that increments and decrements the quantity of an item, my problem here is that the header of these columns are clickable even if I set my Sort Mode to NotSortable:

[image]

I can't seem to find an "enable" property for the headers.

If I click at the header or the button both of them have the functionality to increment/decrement. I want the button to only have that functionality and disable the + header completely.

[image]

Here is my code for the DataGridViewButtonColumn:

```
 private void stockGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
            if (stockGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Add") {
                quantity_change(Add);
            }

            if (stockGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Subtract") {
                quantity_change(Subtract);
            }
}


 void quantity_change(object sender) {
            var row = stockGridView.CurrentRow;

            if (row == null || row.Index < 0)
                return;
            var unit = (sender == Add) ? 1 : -1;
            var quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value) + unit;

            row.Cells["Quantity"].Value = quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check RowIndex value in DataGridViewCellEventArgs. For header row i think it will be negative.
So, if you add test e.RowIndex >= 0 in event handler you should be able to ignore header cell click.
Also, it maybe more consistent to pass e.RowIndex to quantity_change method instead of relying on CurrentRow, but it's up to you.
And one more suggestion - instead of passing Column as a parameter of quantity_change pass integer increment, so that call to quantity_change in case of Add will be quantiy_change(1), in case of Subtract - quantity_change(-1). Then you'll get rid of line where you determine unit variable and a bit simplify your code.

Comment: I just changed: if (stockGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Add") to if (stockGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Add" && e.RowIndex >= 0) and now it WORKS! Thank you so much! Thank you for simplifying the quantity_change function too :D